# changing to Web Workers from AJAX setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a script (below) that asynchronously updates markup on `setInterval`; markup which is generated with jQuery from XML data. This is my attempt at creating a UI in which users can view to see changes happen to the XML data in real-time. However, this is seeming like a round about way of acheiving the desired effect compared to Web Workers API; I am finding out that my AJAX script and `setInterval` function are unreliable; the script appears to freeze or not respond at certain initial loads and after running for long periods of time points . How can I modify my code to use workers instead of AJAX or `setInterval`?

```
            setInterval(refreshXml, 1500);

            function refreshXml() {
              var req = $.get('Administration/data/people.xml');

              req.done(function(xml) {
                    // Update the global XML variable used to create buttons.
                    window.peopleXml = xml;

                    // Clear existing buttons.
                    $('#loadMe').empty();

                    // Display a button for each XML person entity.
                    $(xml).find('fullName').each(function(index) {
                            var fullName = $(this).text();

                            $('<button>', {
                              'class': 'mybutton',
                              value: $(this).siblings('id').text(),
                              text: fullName
                            }).appendTo('#loadMe');          
                    });

                    // Update any person divs that were already visible.
                    $('#toadMe .person').each(function() {
                      // Grabs the ID from data-person-id set earlier.
                      var id = $(this).data('person-id');

                      show_person(id);
                    });
              });
            }

            function show_person(id) {
              $('#person-detail-' + id).remove();

              get_person(id).appendTo('#toadMe');
            }

            function get_person(id) {
              var $person = $(window.peopleXml).find('id:contains(' + id + ')').parent();

              var $div = $('<div>', {
                    'class': 'person',
                    'data-person-id': id,
                    id: 'person-detail-' + id
              });

              $('<h1>', { text: $person.find('firstName').text() }).appendTo($div);
              $('<h1>', { text: $person.find('lastName').text() }).appendTo($div);
              $('<h1>', { text: $person.find('age').text() }).appendTo($div);
              $('<h1>', { text: $person.find('hometown').text() }).appendTo($div);
              $('<h1>', { text: $person.find('job').text() }).appendTo($div);

              return $div;  
            }

            $(document).on('click', '.mybutton', function() {
                    $('#toadMe').empty();
              show_person(this.value);
            });
```

The name of the above script is home.js and here is an example of an index page (index.html) and a worker (my_task.js):

```
            // index.html
            <script>
    var myWorker = new Worker("my_task.js");

    myWorker.onmessage = function (oEvent) {
      console.log("Worker said : " + oEvent.data);
    };

    myWorker.postMessage("ali");




            // my_task.js
    postMessage("I\'m working before postMessage(\'ali\').");

    onmessage = function (oEvent) {
      postMessage("Hi " + oEvent.data);
    };
```

How can I implement home.js in a way in which index.html and my_task.js are implemented? Thanks a ton, I am really just looking for a way to get starting using workers as the next level up since I just recently learned AJAX. Also, I know this could possibly be seen as a broad question so I am willing to improve my question upon request and suggestions.

Comment: I would start by implementing long-polling to reduce the frequency of your ajax requests before using webworkers. Setinterval isn't a very good way of performing ajax requests unless the interval is significant (for example, once per minute). with an interval of 1500ms, slow network connections or periods of slow network speed will cause the requests to pile up. (note, if you're dead-set on using webworkers, longpolling will work in a webworker too.)

Comment: @KevinB Kevin, are you talking about something like this: http://ape-project.org/ ?

Comment: I have no idea how that implements it's functionality. I usually do it myself, it isn't that difficult to implement. Client side you send a request and set a timeout of 30 seconds. Serverside, a request is received, and for 30 seconds, you check for new data on an interval. If new data is found, return to client, if 30 seconds passes, return empty data to client. rinse repeat.